# How to implement / use analyzer in Xapian 1.4.5?

Tags: lucene, xapian

I searched in Google but didn't find any clue related to implement analyzer in Xapian, even Xapian may not support using analyzer like lucene. In another word, I can't extend to support in Chinese. Am I right?

I searched in Xapian C++ API, only found [TermGenerator](https://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1TermGenerator.html) which may related to extract word. There is a flag named `FLAG_CJK_NGRAM`, it can split UTF-8 CJK word, let's say ABCD, it will split it into AB, BC, CD and A, B, C, D. That's very simple and straightforward. I suppose I need a more accurate solution, it seems I need implement or migrate mature solution(like [jieba](https://github.com/yanyiwu/cppjieba)) to Xapian. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The TermGenerator (and the QueryParser, which goes hand in hand) supports CJK ngram splitting, which is possibly what you're looking for, by adding `FLAG_CJK_NGRAM`. For TermGenerator, this is used by calling [`set_flags()`](https://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1TermGenerator.html#aa0d1f0ee309227852654e589ef441517); for QueryParser you pass flags in to [`parse_query()`](https://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1QueryParser.html#a73d32cc7f862ab2e3fdd7da61f352fb2) (it's common to boolean OR in new flags with `FLAG_DEFAULT`, otherwise you'll turn off features you probably want to keep on).

In all other respects you should be able to use Xapian as normal, such as in [the practical example](https://getting-started-with-xapian.readthedocs.io/en/latest/practical_example/index.html) from the "getting started" guide. (Note that although the example is in python, this will work in other wrapped languages, and directly from C++. [The source code for the getting started guide](https://github.com/xapian/xapian-docsprint) has the code examples in some other languages.)

From the documentation of `FLAG_CJK_NGRAM`:

> With this enabled, spans of CJK characters are split into unigrams and bigrams, with the unigrams carrying positional information. Non-CJK characters are split into words as normal.

If you want to do something else, then you currently have to write your own term generation and query parsing code.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have tried `FLAG_CJK_NGRAM`, but that is very simple TermGenerator which just split word ABCD to AB, BC, CD and A, B, C, D. So I suppose I need implement my own term generation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, if you want something more powerful then you'll need to write your own. I believe the latest version is somewhat more subtle, but not necessarily enough to do what you want.